# How do I visually design my database with Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, typescript, entity-framework-core

I am wondering myself, how I should design my database scheme (in terms of efficiency and visuality).

I am developing a ASP.NET Core application with Angular 2 and I am using [Entity Framework Core](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/) ([`"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0"`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore)), since its my favourite ORM. I definitely prefer the SQL Server 2012, but if there are better options for designing my scheme available for other database management systems, I could switch to something else like PostgreSQL.

EntityFrameworkCore however doesn't support designing the DataContext (with all its POCO classes) with the EDMX designer anymore.

Can you give me any advice how I can design my database visually and automatically generate my POCO classes (and maybe also my TypeScript classes)?

Can you recommend me a good tool for designing my scheme? (At least more convenient than SQL Server Management Studio. I liked the EDMX designer)

### EDIT 2019-03-28

Since the latest changelog [(18.0 Preview 7)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) of SQL Server Management Studio announced, that **[Database Diagrams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#deprecated-features) are deprecated**, I am really in need of an alternative to visualize my databases, as soon as possible.

### EDIT 2019-04-03

Since someone might stumble upon this question and no one provided an answer for my question, yet... Here you go: [VS Extension: Entity Developer ORM Designer for LINQ to SQL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DevartSoftware.EntityDeveloperforLINQtoSQL)

### EDIT 2019-07-15

From the [SSMS 19.1 Changelog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017):

> Database diagrams were added back into SSMS.

Comment: I am also looking for something like EDMX designer to visually design my DB. Have you found anything? Best regards

Comment: Two non-answers, then it gets closed, and it's still bombing Google. Gotta love this site sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer to start with the database, you can use whatever design tools you find most useful for whichever database platform you prefer to create the database, and then use EF commands to scaffold your model and context from the database. You can execute commands from the Package Manager Console just as with migrations in previous versions of EF:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=yourServer;Database=yourDb;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

The official documentation covers [reverse engineering a model from an existing database](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html#reverse-engineer-your-model)

Comment: Yeah, I was asking for the specific "design tools" you mentioned. Not for scaffolding instrucitons.

Comment: @WΩLLE - ˈvɔlə: I agree so much with you! Visual designers have been such a great improvement for developers. Nowadays I have the feeling that they (MS) return to the "good old times" of commands. I call that major regressions; I'm really not a fan of command prompts. 
When I started programming there were only command lines. What a fantastic experience when I first used MSVC 1.0 (yes I'm getting old), then 1.5, and now VS2019. 
It is so easier and friendly *not* to have to type commands (although you need to know more or less what happens under the hood).

Comment: @ggo Haha  Those words could come from my mouth.

Answer (score 2):

You can scaffold DbContext with enities using `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` command from terminal (console). So you can design DB in whatever way you want and then run scaffold command and you'll get your generated DbContext and classes.

Here's documentation on command:
https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold

Comment: Btw, I was asking for the specific "[...] way you want" you mentioned. Not for scaffolding instructions.